# John goes to the cinema with Kate and (with) Ann

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, semantics, conjunction-reduction

What's the difference between general public's interpretations of these:

1. John goes to the cinema with Kate and Ann.
2. John goes to the cinema with Kate and with Ann.

Answer (score 3):

Perceptually, though not definitively…

1. All three go to the cinema together.
2. John only goes to the cinema with one girl each time.

Comment: I agree that these are the default (pragmatic) readings, Tetsujin. But can you add a supporting reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - tbh, I wouldn't know where to start to look for one.